# ORDER BY not putting SELECT statement in numerical order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a SELECT statement.

```
USE SCRUMAPI2

DECLARE @userParam VARCHAR(100)
    ,@statusParam VARCHAR(100)

SET @userParam = '%'
SET @statusParam = '%'

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY PDT.[Name] DESC
        ) AS 'RowNumber'
    ,PDT.[Name] AS Project
    ,(
        CASE WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                    ) THEN 'KanBan' WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                    ) THEN 'Sprint' END
        ) AS ProjectType
    ,STY.[Number] StoryNumber
    ,STY.Title AS StoryTitle
    ,TSK.[Name] AS Task
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), STY.Effort) AS Effort
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TSK.OriginalEstimateHours) AS OriginalEstimateHours
    ,TSK.STATUS AS STATUS
FROM Task TSK
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
WHERE TSK.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
    AND TSK.STATUS LIKE @statusParam
GROUP BY STY.[Number]
    ,TSK.STATUS
    ,STY.Title
    ,PDT.[Name]
    ,TSK.CreateDate
    ,TSK.[Name]
    ,STY.KanBanProductId
    ,STY.SprintId
    ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours
    ,STY.Effort
```

My issue that that although I have the ORDER BY sorting by story number first it is not returning as expected (below is column STY.[Number]):

[image]

As you can see it foes from 33 to 4 to 42, I want it in numerical order so that 4 would be between 3 and 5 not 33 and 42. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do all of your names begin with `SUPP-`?  Your order by is working properly you are sorting on a string. You need to alter your code to order by the numeric portion of your name.

Comment: You're sorting on a character field, not numeric.  You would need to pull out the numeric portion if you want to sort on that specifically.

Comment: No, there are many alphabetic codes but they are all on the same format CMIS-550 for example.

Comment: You would need to remove the string part and then cast to an int in order to sort numerically - I don't know if you can cast without removing it first

Comment: I don't see where you order by `STY.[Number]` at all.

Comment: Relying on the ordering used in generating `ROW_NUMBER` is not guaranteed. You need an `ORDER BY` on the query itself if you want a specific order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the structure of your data (with a constant prefix), probably the easiest way to get what you want is:

```
order by len(STY.[Number]), STY.[Number]
```

This orders first by the length and then by the number itself.

Answer (score 3):

Those are strings. Do you really expect SQL Server to be able to identify that there is a number at character 6 in every single row in the result, and instead of ordering by character 6, they pretend that, say, `SUPP-5` is actually `SUPP-05`? If that worked for you, people who expect the opposite behavior (to treat the whole string as a string) would be complaining. The real fix is to store this information in two separate columns, since it is clearly two separate pieces of data.

In the meantime, you can hack something, like:

```
ORDER BY LEFT(col, 4), CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(col, 6, 255)));
```

As Martin explained, this should be on the outer query, not just used to generate a `ROW_NUMBER()` - generating a row number alone doesn't guarantee the results will be ordered by that value. And this will only work with additional checks to ensure that every single row has a value following the dash that can be converted to an int. As soon as you have `SUPP-5X` this will break.

Answer (score 1):

It's sorting by the string in lexicography order. To get numerical ordering you need to extract the number from the string (with substring()) and cast it to integer.